# Alert user when redirects to other page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I alert user when leaving, going back (back button on browser), refreshing the page and closing the tab to save data before leaving the page in angularJS.

**Special condition:**

I have two places (one link and one button) on the page which leads user to a common partial page. I want to alert user about saving the data when he clicks on the link, but want to redirect to other page without notifying the user when he redirects from button.

I am using the below code to alert user.

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {

    alert("Hello $routeChangeStart ");
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Well you got the start, now you can go on the Angular doc and see other cases : **[Route documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route)**

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find any way to identify which event or button has raised this redirect request. Is there any way to identify this?

Comment: Wow sorry, I'm a little lost. I wanted to redirect you to `UI-router`. It's more efficient than the embedded routing, and you have a `$stateChangeSuccess` in it, which is triggered every time you reach your state.